# Appropriate algorithm to replace three nested loops - nested comments

Tags: php, algorithm, tree

So I'm in the process of writing a commenting system with nested replies. I've got the storage and retrieval part down, and am ending up with an array of comment objects that each have a replies property, which is itself an array of comment objects.

The maximum depth I'm allowing is 3 - or a reply to a reply.

I'm looking for an appropriately efficient replacement for three nested loops to display the comments, or looping through the top layer, then looping through their replies, then looping through THEIR replies as this is not scalable.

Ok, so I've been asked for some code:

```
class Comment{
    public $replies = array();
    public $content;
}
```

So a comment object contains an array of replies, which are themselves comment objects. This goes three layers deep so I have an array of top level comments, which each contain an array of replies, which each contain an array of replies.

I want to find a solution that's superior to this, as it comes out to O(n^3) i believe:

```
foreach($comments as $c){
    //do some stuff to display the comment here
    foreach($c->replies as $r){
        //do some stuff to display the replies here
        foreach($r->replies as $rr){
            //do some stuff to display replies to replies here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To even get a remote chance for a qualified answer, I think you must post some code - like an example of those "_three nested loops_" .. :)

Comment: @davidkonrad - fixed, please see added code.

Comment: Are your `comments` and `replies` and `replies to replies` saved in a mysql table? If yes, might I suggest using JOIN queries.

Comment: @Jhn - I'm not sure how that helps my problem? Join queries are not a solution for how to efficiently loop through a tree data structure...

Comment: So for the solution you're looking for you want the entire comment chain loaded into memory at the same time? Not like a lazy load where the replies are retrieved on request.

Comment: @jwatts1980 - at this point I already have the comments in memory, I want the fastest way to get through them all. If that means reorganizing the data structure I'm cool with that as long as I can keep the replies under their parents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the running time for the your code is not `O(n^3)`, but `O(total number of replies)`, as it will iterate through all the replies exactly once (the loops are not running from `1` to `n`, they're foreach loops and the numbers of iterations they perform depend on the size of the array).

There's no better running time for performing this task, as you want to do something with each reply, so the lower bound of this task is `O(total number of replies)`.

What I would do though, is rewrite the code and use a recursion function, because your code is not very flexible to changes, if one day you'll decide you allow 4 levels of replies, you'll have to rewrite this code, while if you use recursion, you wouldn't.

Like I said, it is not expected to enhance the performance, but merely a better practice.

Comment: Since theoretically an unlimited number of comments could be added it will indeed be O(n^3). N is used because we don't know the total number of comments, and indeed we do not until we pull them from the database.

Comment: @RhodesianHunter What is `n` in this case? does each comment necessarily have the same number of replies? not necessarily. `n` should represent the size of the input, which in this case, is the total number of replies, no matter in which level, and the algorithm runs in linear time in the size of this input.

Comment: Think of a commenting system like disqus - there could be an unlimited number of replies to any comment in levels 0-2 - We use n in this context because n could be any number from 0 - infinity (theoretically)

Comment: O(n^3) only applies if each level 1 comment contains an array of every other comment, and then each one of those contains the entire array of every other comment.
 
Optimally, each comment *should* contain an array of only it's own replies, and likewise to level 3. That means that each comment/reply should only exist once in your comment/reply tree. That means each one is only processed once, so O(n).

Comment: Ron Teller & jwatts - Ok, that makes sense. I was looking at it the wrong way, thank you for correcting me. @jwatts1980 do you also believe a recursive function doing essentially the same thing is the ideal way to handle this?

Comment: Absolutely. Recursion is definitely the way to go. At some point, such as on the user interface side, or possibly through some global variable/setting, you can limit the depth of the replies. On past projects, I've used a parameter in the recursive function called "level" or something to track how deep I am into the recursion.

Comment: I will make the point that the above applies only to the processing side, assuming you've already loaded the comments. But in the load phase, the same question applies. Optimally, each comment/reply is processed and loaded once, rather than having to load level 1, then loop through those to load level 2, then loop through each level 1 and level 2 to load level 3.